# Add Keyboard Shortcuts to Windows Movies & TV App

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player

I really like the design of the native Windows [Movies & TV](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/movies-tv/9wzdncrfj3p2?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) app. However, it laks of some essential keyboard shortcuts. Is it possible to achieve the following behaviour for the app:

1. Keyboard shortcut for previous/next movie (there are buttons at the side)
2. Keyboard shortcut to jump forward/backward for 10 seconds (there are buttons at the bottom)

---

I'm aware that using VLC would probably solve this issue, however, to my knowledge, it is not possible to make VLC look like this app with any [VLC skin](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. Doesn't appear to be one for next/previous movie, but there is what MSFT calls "Go Back" which takes you to the main menu from which you can select video. The shortcut is ALT + Left Arrow or sometimes Window Key + Backspace.
2. This is so nicely hidden and undocumented that I had to discover it entirely by accident.  The shortcut will work only when you've just moved the movie-position slider around and left the mouse in the slider area -- then you can use just the left or right arrow keys.  When you do that, the slider box will be highlighted.  What's weird is once you've done that, then the left/right arrow keys will do what you want even if you move to another window and then come back to bring Movies & TV back into focus.  What could possibly be more intuitive???????